# Detect WM_MOUSEMOVE on different window

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

While my C# WinForms app is running, I need to detect when the mouse pointer is moved over a 3rd party application.

I've done some Google'ing but I can't seem to find a useful code example that shows how to set up a Hook Procedure to another application using C# to detect Windows Messages.

Can someone please show me how to setup a C# hook procedure so I can detect the WM_MOUSEMOVE message on another app (e.g. Notepad.exe)?

Comment: There are probably a variety of ways to solve your problem. It might help us choose the best one if we knew more context. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: When the mouse pointer is moved over a particular area of the 3rd party application window I need to display a window that looks like a tooltip..So I thought if I could find some C# code that showed me how to capture the WM_MOUSEMOVE windows message, I could then work out when the mouse was over the 3rd party app. I just need to monitor the windows messages (and don't need to make any changes to the 3rd party application window).

Comment: You could use a low level mouse hook

Comment: Can you please show me an example of a Mouse Hook in C# that monitors another application window?

Comment: You can use Google for stuff like that: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589468.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is the C# Low Level Mouse Hook code I was looking for, from the [blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589468.aspx](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589468.aspx) link (that David Heffernan posted)

```
class InterceptMouse
{
    private static LowLevelMouseProc _proc = HookCallback;
    private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

    public static void Main()
    {
        _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
        Application.Run();
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
    }

    private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelMouseProc proc)
    {
        using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
        {
            return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, proc,
                GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
        }
    }

    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private static IntPtr HookCallback(
        int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 &&
            MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam)
        {
            MSLLHOOKSTRUCT hookStruct = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT));
            Console.WriteLine(hookStruct.pt.x + ", " + hookStruct.pt.y);
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    private const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;

    private enum MouseMessages
    {
        WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201,
        WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202,
        WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200,
        WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A,
        WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204,
        WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct POINT
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
    {
        public POINT pt;
        public uint mouseData;
        public uint flags;
        public uint time;
        public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
        LowLevelMouseProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
        IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
}
```