# Detecting a button/context menu pressed in another application

Tags: c#, user-interface, windows-messages

I have a 3rd party application that make changes to a 3rd party component that my application interacts with. 
This component cannot send me any information, but can be changed by my application as well.

I'd like to know when a user presses a button or a command in the context menu that can change the state of the component.

Can I hook to the windows message the 3rd application listens to and know which button was pressed? 
If so - how? and if not - is there another way to do it?

Comment: If you can see the messages with spy++ you could try the solution offered in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497289/detect-wm-mousemove-on-different-window)

Comment: @rene: Ok, but I need to know which control responded to the message...

Comment: If your component doesn't send message that are picked up by spy++ you're out of luck